# Only webform administrators are allowed to access this page and create new submissions

Tags: webforms

I first realized unprivileged users couldn't access webforms and I made a support request elsewhere for that, as suggested.
Only today I noticed an administrator sees the form and above it an info box that says *Only webform administrators are allowed to access this page and create new submissions*.

Please consider I get the mentioned message **both with webforms built before the upgrade of Drupal and the of Webform module - I made a long trip from Drupal 8 to Drupal 10 - and with a fresh dummy form recently created**.

I noticed such an issue has already been reported as bug in the past, but that's something dated around 2018...

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2938366

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2966923

Thanks in advance!

Andrea

Comment: Can you confirm that you have executed the Webform settings repair?

Comment: @cilefen, you mean that action I can launch at the bottom of the page /admin/structure/webform/config/advanced? I just tried, with no luck. I also tried with "drush webform-repair".

Comment: Can you confirm that the permissions on the affected forms are such that a non-administrator should be able to view them?

Comment: @cilefen actually that was the issue I noticed first: an unprivileged user faces an "Access denied" and "You are not authorized to access this page" - though I read that in Italian. Only later on, being logged in as an administrator, I noticed the dark notice box telling "Only webform administrators are allowed to access this page and create new submissions".